# Benefits of adding associations in ActiveRecord Models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, rake, datamapper

I am creating active record associations for the first time and would like to understand what to expect after I have added them. I am using rails 3.2.14

**I have 3 tables Users, Applications and Jobs**

1] In application table I have added User_Id and Job_id as the foreign key column, since an application belongs to a User and a Job.

2] I have also added the necessary associations.

3] After adding the foreign key columns and the associations, is running rake db:migrate sufficient or do I have to do anything else to complete the relational modeling ?

**Some Context**

Now when I create a new application after clicking on a job link, I was hoping that the job_id and user_id would be automagically populated by the framework in Application:create method where it performs

```
Application.new(params[:application])
```

However , seems like the foreign_key columns are not populated by the framework and I would have to manually extract the relevant job_id and user_id in the create method and populate it to the application.

One advantage of not adding associations is if I later I realize some relation is has_and_belong_to_many instead of has_many I can just handle that in the tables since no associations are 'frozen' at that point.

**I have following questions:**

1]what was the benefit of defining a associations in the model. I could have just added foreign key columns and handled them without associating them in models.

2] What other things I should expect (would make my life easier eventually) by adding associations in the models ?

Here are the models:

```
Models:
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      rolify
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
      # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
      attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
      attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :user_id
      validates_presence_of :email

    end


    class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :company, :desc, :location, :application_id, :applicant_id

      belongs_to :recruiters, :class_name => "User"
      has_many :applications
      has_many :applicants,:class_name => "User", through: :applications
    end

    class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :applicant_email, :applicant_name, :recruiter_id, :applicant_id, :user_id


      belongs_to :jobs
      belongs_to :applicants, :class_name => "User"
    end
```

**Note**
Feel free to provide links to videos, blogs in the comment section, where these things are explained in a simple manner . I did not find the the official doc that helpful to understand all steps, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html and there is no relevant rails-cast I can find

Answer (score 0):

1) Because they make common operations simpler and easier in your code. Its the Active Record pattern essentially. Why write code to handle this stuff yourself, like queries etc when this is already built in. It reduces code significantly and makes you're queries significantly easier to read.
2) This is too broad to answer, so I won't.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you give any example where associations make writing easier queries ? Also what common operations are made simpler?